# How to change asp.net DropDownList SelectedValue using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have three dropdownlist controls in my asp.net web app project from which the user will choose items. What I want is that the user must not choose the same values, meaning that the value selected in the one Dropdownlist can not be selected in the other dropdownlist, and if the user tries to select the same value I want to reset the selectedValue property to that dropdownlist. Is there anyway I can achieve this using javascript? It's better to make it on the client side.

Thank you!

The Dropdownlist Looks like this: [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdjiK.png)

Comment: How are you rendering your dropdowns ? Share some relevant code. You can listen to `change` event on the first dropdown and read the selection and delete that  option from  second dropdown

Comment: The dropdownlists are bound to database table.

Comment: If possible i need to reset the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First add same class name  in all three dropdowns. e.g
   'class=dropdownClass'
2. Add dropdown Number as attribute in all
   three dropdowns -> 'dropdownNo=1' , 'dropdownNo=2' , 'dropdownNo=3'
3. Also add ids (it must be different)-> dropdownId1 , dropdownId2 ,
   dropdownId3 respectivitely

   ```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

   $('.dropdownClass').on('change', function () {
       //when ever any dropdown change (class name is same)
       //get the attribe no

       var CurrentdropdownNo = $(this).attr('dropdownNo')
       var CurrentdropdownValue = $(this).val();

       if (CurrentdropdownNo == 1) {
           var value2 =  $('#dropdownId2').val() ;
           var value3 =  $('#dropdownId3').val() ;
          //check with dropdown 2,3
           if (CurrentdropdownValue == value2 || CurrentdropdownValue == value3)
           {
               //reset the current dropdown
               //do stuff here , what you want
           }

      }
       if (CurrentdropdownNo == 2) {
           var value1 = $('#dropdownId1').val();
           var value3 = $('#dropdownId3').val();
           //check with dropdown 1,3
           if (CurrentdropdownValue == value1 || CurrentdropdownValue == value3) {
               //reset the current dropdown
               //do stuff here , what you want
           }
      }
       if (CurrentdropdownNo == 3) {
           var value1 = $('#dropdownId1').val();
           var value2 = $('#dropdownId2').val();
          //check with dropdown 1,2
           if (CurrentdropdownValue == value1 || CurrentdropdownValue == value2) {
               //reset the current dropdown
               //do stuff here , what you want
           }

      }

   })
   ```

   })

> Note: Change class name Or id name as want ..

Answer (score 0):

Use change Event of every dropdownlist
this is just one change event that i use for Dropdownlist. Do same thing for other drowpdownlists.

```
var firstDropVal="";
var SecndDropVal="";
var ThrdDropVal ="";


    $("#dropOne").change(function () {

            var firstDropVal = $("#dropOne").val();
           var firstDropVal = $("#dropTwo").val();
          var firstDropVal = $("#dropThree").val();

        if(firstDropVal == SecndDropVal){

         $("#dropOne").val(0)// Or Do what you want to do 
         }


        });
```